# wpf gradient brush like the picture

Tags: wpf, gradient, brush, behind

[image]

I am trying to make a brush like the picture.
What should I do?

In System.Drawing.Color, it was done as follows.

**C# WinForm**

```
Rectangle drawRc = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
Color[] colors = { Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0) };
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddRectangle(drawRc);
PathGradientBrush pdb = new PathGradientBrush(path)
{
    CenterPoint = new PointF(x2, y2),
    CenterColor = patCol,
    SurroundColors = colors
};

g.FillRectangle(pdb, drawRc);
pdb.Dispose();
```

**wpf**

```
double StartX = 1.00d, StartY = 1.00d;
var list = new List<GradientStop>();
list.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0));
list.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 1));
                        
var gradient = new GradientStopCollection(list);
var brush = new RadialGradientBrush(gradients) {
    MappingMode = BrushMappingMode.RelativeToBoundingBox,
    GradientOrigin = new Point(StartX, StartY),
    RadiusX = 0.7,
    RadiusY = 0.7,
    Center = new Point(0.7,0.7)
};
```

Comment: I think you could probably achieve that effect using two overlaid clipped lineargradienbrushes.  When you want something non standard like that though but you can produce it as a picture then I'd suggest just keep it simple and use an imagebrush.

Comment: Is it possible to express two overlapping gradients with one brush? Are you talking about implementing two rectangular gradient brushes? @Andy

Comment: No. I was thinking 2 brushes with triangular clips.  Not so sure that could give you an exact match though.
BUT 
AN IMAGEBRUSH COULD DO WHATEVER PICTURE YOU CAN CREATE.

Comment: I should be able to save the brush later as xml or json data. Can ImageBrush also store brush values? @Andy

Comment: You can serialise a picture as a char array. But why not save as a jpg? You could alernatvely build an images dynamically and calculate the colour of each pixel. If you wanted to configure the algorithm via xaml you could write a markup extension or converter if you prefer data driven.